# Can Logstash, ElasticSearch and Kibana be used to log http requests?

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I need something like ODBC logging on Linux.  There are some older libraries for Apache and MySQL, but I do not want to use them.  I found the ELK stack and installed it.  Can Logstash, ElasticSearch and Kibana be used as an http logging mechanism, so I can see user, ip address, etc.?

Using Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 2):

Surely it is possible. A simple google search will give you more than one very good documentation on that.

See here: [Logstash Configuration Example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html#config-examples)

Apache's log patterns are included in the default Logstash patterns, so it is fairly easy to set up a filter for it, see more here: [Adding Logstash Filters To Improve Centralized Logging](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/adding-logstash-filters-to-improve-centralized-logging).

Comment: Absolutely. We have a multi-TB ELK instance for our HTTP requests.

Comment: @MarkHenderson could you share an approximation of the number of log messages/second and the hardware it's running on? I'm curious. Thanks.

Comment: @AndréBorie sure. The stats about the kind of traffic you can [find here](http://stackexchange.com/performance) (although I think it's a bit outdated now). Our ELK cluster is not the one from that page though (that's for searching the sites). We have six ElasticSearch boxes for logging, each with 2x E5-2660, 192GB of RAM and 43.65TB of usable storage. However that's also used for a bunch of other logstashing stuff, not just HTTP.

Comment: @MarkHenderson thanks for sharing, that's some pretty expensive hardware.